# Is there a way to copy data with a macro/button filter?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, macros, button-remapping

I have a worksheet with employee ids on the top and dates on the side.

Then I need to put a Y or a N at there name every day I have 96 employees so it's really long. Is there away with a button or macro that if a person gets a Y I can get those people copied to another sheet and if someone new gets a Y it will take them over as well. So that it's easier to just narrow down the people with the Y

[image: http://i.imgur.com/tNc2Nan.jpg]

Comment: Screen shots!!!! :) - or at least, use the post try and show the data and how it is laid out! So, you have to manually add a Y or N every day. At the end of this, you want to copy all of those rows with a Y to another document. Is that correct?

Comment: Yeah pretty much that's what I want and if a new person gets a Y that will add it on to the new sheet.

Comment: http://imgur.com/tNc2Nan So here is a sample as you can see some have a Y and some have a N I want to make a thing so when a Y does appear it will put them on a new sheet with people that got a Y on any date add them to a separate sheet with the same layout as the sample

Comment: It will put what to a new worksheet? I assume the column, or just the persons name, or the entire row?

Comment: I want the full column to go over

Comment: So if I was to run it sam and bobbie wouldn't get copied over just the other people inless later on they get a Y.

Answer (score 1):

This VBa does what I think you want... Your question isn't the clearest.

Remember, with VBa, create a copy of the file first as it has no undo feature

```
Option Explicit

Sub FindYeTheMapOfTreasure()


Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A:F").Clear
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A:B").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:B").Value


    Dim row As Integer
    row = 2

    Do While Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & row).Value <> ""

    If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & row).Value = "Y" Then
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C:C").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C:C").Value
    End If

    If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & row).Value = "Y" Then
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D:D").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D:D").Value
    End If

    If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & row).Value = "Y" Then
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("E:E").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E:E").Value
    End If

    If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F" & row).Value = "Y" Then
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("F:F").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F:F").Value
    End If

    If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G" & row).Value = "Y" Then
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("G:G").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G:G").Value
    End If
    row = row + 1
    Loop


End Sub
```

Sheet1

[image]

After I run it, sheet2 looks like

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much I'm going to try this out. Yeah I know, I know what I want in my head but explaining it is a bit harder lol.